# Navigation Menu with sub menus using multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Hi I'm developing a cms like wordpress but I'm kinda stuck on the dynamic menus on my cms. I have no problem loading parent menus, the problem is the child menus it for some reason the menu can only have one child menu on my case plus it doesn't load the correct child

Here is my database structure for you guys to see if I did something wrong here 
[image: databaseStructure]

Now my php function is this:

```
      function GenerateNavHTML($nav)
{
  global $db;
  $html = '';
  $html = '<ul class="nav navbar-nav">';
  foreach($nav as $page)
  {
      $html .= '<li>';

      if ($page['isParent'] == 1  ){ $html .= '<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">' . $page['name'] . ' <span class="caret"></span></a>';
          $html .='<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">';
          $sql = "SELECT * FROM lm_menu WHERE parent = :var";
          $res = $db->prepare($sql);
          $res->bindParam("var",$page['parent'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
          $res->execute();
          $sub = $res->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
          foreach ($sub as $key) {
              if($key['parent'] == $page['name']){
                  $html .='<li><a href="#">'.$key['name'].'</a></li></ul>';
              }
          }

       }else { $html .='<a href="' . $page['ref'] . '">' . $page['name'] . '</a>'; }

      $html .= '</li>';
  }
  $html .='</ul>';
  return $html;
}

        global $db;
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM lm_menu";
        $res = $db->prepare($sql);
        $res->execute();
        $nav = $res->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


 GenerateNavHTML($nav)
```

I need my array to be dynamic based on my database. I tried to look for an answer/s first but none seems to be related to my problem here..

Comment: You are doing too much at once. I would recommend that you scrap this code and start over. Instead of doing everything in the same function, you should divide and conquer. Create one function that figures out which menu items you need, one that fetches them from the database, one that creates a multidimensional array out of the database results, and finally one that creates the HTML using that array. Look at it as several smaller problems, instead of one big problem. It is easier.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very quick overview. This is tested code.
Example, more detailed descriptions, and code are here: [Example](http://ispeedlink.com/so/menu/)
I have never done a user configurable menu before so the code is not refined.
It has zero HTML or CSS errors.  Scores 100% on the W3C mobileOK validator and YSlow.  Page speed score is 99% (flaw in PageSpeed).
Code execution time is less than 1 millisecond.

I prefer *form / button* over <a> for buttonst; for menu links because the CSS is simplified.  And works in Browsers that do not support display:inline-block as BUTTON is inline-block by default.

**Database Table**

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `menu` (
      `Column` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `Sort` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `MenuText` char(16) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
      `Destination` char(64) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
      `Class` int(11) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`Column`,`Sort`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**PHP**

```
$classes=array('"top"','"sub"','"link"');
$endDiv = '';
$subs = 'var subs = [[],';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `menu` WHERE 1 ORDER BY `Column` ASC, `Sort` ASC";
$results = mysql_query($sql);
if (mysql_errno() > 0){$error = mysql_error();echo "<p>$sql<br/>$error</p>";}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results, MYSQL_NUM)) {
  $class = $classes[$row[4]];
  if ($row[4] == 1){
    echo "<div id=\"i$row[0]$row[1]\" class=$class><form action=\"$row[3]\"><div class=\"inline\"><button type=\"submit\">$row[2]</button></div></form></div>\n";
  }
  elseif ($row[4] == 2){
    echo "$endDiv<div  id=\"d$row[0]$row[1]\" class=\"col\">\n<div class=$class><form action=\"$row[3]\"><div class=\"inline\"><button type=\"submit\">$row[2]</button></div></form></div>\n";
  $endDiv="</div>\n";
  $subs .= '[],';
  }
  else{
  echo"$endDiv<div class=\"col\">\n<button type=\"button\" class=$class onclick=\"showSub($row[0])\">$row[2]</button>\n";
    $endDiv="</div>\n";
  $subs .= '[],';
  }
}
$subs = substr($subs,0,-1) . '];';
echo <<<EOT
$endDiv</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
$subs
var selected = -1;
function getDivs() {
  var did = '';
  var col = 0;
  var sub = 0;
  for (var div=0; div<divs.length; div++){
    did = divs[div].getAttribute("id");
    if (did == null){continue;}
    if (did.substring(0,1) == "i"){
      col = parseInt(did.substring(1,2),10);
      subs[col].push(div);
    }
    else if (did.substring(0,1) == "d"){
      col = parseInt(did.substring(1,2),10);
    subs[col].push(0);
    }
  } 
  hideSubs();

}
function showSub(c) {
  hideSubs();
  if (selected == c){selected=-1;return;}
  selected = c;
  for (var sub=0; sub<subs[c].length; sub++){
  divs[subs[c][sub]].style.display = 'block';
  }
}
function hideSubs() {
  var sub = 0;
  var col = 0;
  var div = 1;
  var cnt = subs.length;
  while(true){
    if (div++ > cnt){break;}
    if (subs[col][0] < 1){col++;continue;}
    for (var sub=0; sub<subs[col].length; sub++){
    if (subs[col][sub] == null){continue;}
      divs[subs[col][sub]].style.display = 'none';
    }

    col++;
  }
}
window.onload = getDivs;
//]]>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: I'm old.  That is how I did it back in the day.  I assume you know how to convert my code to non-depreciated.  Feel free to Edit.